# Discussion Board. Can I remove the quoted text?

Tags: 2007

Is there a way to remove the quoted text when replying in a discussion board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions detailed [here](http://carlosyelsoftware.heroku.com/2011/04/01/borrar-texto-respuesta-sharepoint-duscussion-board/)

It's kind of a hack, but it works.

Comment: Does it work for SharePoint 2010 Discussion Board? If yes, can you provide more details about this?

Comment: Well, I did it in a 2007 solution but then it was installed in a 2010 farm. I believe it should work. First edit the page by appending this at the end `?pageview=shared&toolpanelview=2`. Then, do what is detailed in the response's link